# Creating randomly concatenated combinations of data in two columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a random set of concatenated data from two different columns.

Column A contains different words in each row, e.g.:
Word 1
Word 2
Word 3

Column B contains different words in each row, e.g.:
Word A
Word B
Word C

Desired output to Column C is the randomized concatenation of Columns A & B with a space in between, eg.:
Word 1 Word C
Word 3 Word B
Word 2 Word A

I get the error for the row that starts with 'Cells(j, 3) =':

> Method 'Range' of object 'Global_' failed.

```vb
Sub Createrandomwords()

Dim randomNum1 As Integer
Dim randomNum2 As Integer
Dim i As Integer

'Column C will have 8 rows of randomly created words

For i = 1 To 8
    randomNum1 = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 26) 'number of rows in column A is 26
    randomNum2 = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 33) 'number of rows in column B is 33
    Cells(i, 3) = Range("Cells(randomNum1, 1)") & " " & Range("Cells(randomNum2, 2)")
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `Cells(i, 3) = Cells(randomNum1, 1) & " " & Cells(randomNum2, 2)`?

Comment: Will your output include Word 1 Word A (I mean the same row as random)?

Comment: Thank you Raymond Wu, that works perfectly. I had misunderstood how to use the Range vs the Cell function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the code you posted in your question, you would notice that `"Cells(randomNum1, 1)"` is treated as a literal string as you have enclosed `Cells(randomNum1, 1)` in quotes ( "" ).

Since you are referring to a single cell, you can omit `Range` and just use `Cell` instead:

```
Cells(i, 3) = Cells(randomNum1, 1) & " " & Cells(randomNum2, 2)
```

Comment: Great thank you for this Raymond, much appreciated